# Two problems in code (open file with console string, and delete[])

Tags: c, string, file, console

I have a couple of questions. If I manually enter a file path, the function fopen_s always fails, but if I set the same path by code, the file opens without problems. My second issue is "delete[] bytes" and "delete[] locatie" doesn't compile, I get

> error C2065: 'delete' undeclared identifier

and

> C2059: syntax error ']'

and I have no clue why. The ASM part is an optimized loop btw.

```
char* getline()
{
    char line[50];  
    char *eof;
    line[0] = '\0'; 
    line[sizeof(line)-1] = ~'\0';  
    eof = fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char* locatie, *bytes, c;
    FILE* bestand;
    int i, size;
    struct stat st;

    printf_s("Voer het pad van het bestand in en druk op enter.\n");
    locatie = getline();
    locatie[strlen(locatie)-1] ='\0';
    locatie = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\haha.txt"; // <-- this line

    if ((i = fopen_s(&bestand, locatie, "r" )) != 0)
    {
        printf_s("Het bestand bestaat niet, of kon niet worden geopend!");
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    stat(locatie, &st);
    size = st.st_size;
    bytes = (char*)malloc(i+1);
    i = 0;

    loop:
    c = fgetc(bestand);
    __asm
    {
        movsx eax, byte ptr [c]
        cmp eax, 0x0FFFFFFFF
        je Break
        mov eax, dword ptr [bytes]
        add eax, dword ptr [i]
        mov cl, byte ptr [c]
        xor cl, 32
        mov byte ptr [eax], cl  
        mov eax, dword ptr [i]  
        add eax, 1
        mov dword ptr [i], eax
        jmp loop
    }

    Break:
    fclose(bestand);
    bytes[i] = '\0';
    printf(bytes);

    locatie = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\haha.cpt";
    fopen_s(&bestand, locatie, "w");
    fprintf_s(bestand, "%c", bytes);
    fclose(bestand);
    delete[] bytes;
    delete[] locatie;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You did not get a bunch of compiler warnings about this code?

Comment: Apparently not, the value of eof returned and I could see it. That's why I didn't take a second look at the getline() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`delete[]` is C++, use `free()` in C.

The program has undefined behaviour as the function `getline()` does not `return` anything. Do not attempt to fix this by returning `line` (or `eof` which is either `NULL` or points to `line`) but you need to `malloc()` a new buffer and return it or pass a buffer to `getline()` to be populated.

This is a mistake:

```
fprintf_s(bestand, "%c", bytes);
```

the format specifier `"%c"` expects an argument of type `char` but `bytes` is a `char*`. Use `"%s"` instead:

```
fprintf_s(bestand, "%s", bytes);
```

Comment: I had to use %c, if I use %s the result is all messed up. And the applications crashes for some reason if I use "free()", I removed it because it wasn't necessary anyway (since the application exits).

Comment: @Ruben, this is incorrect as `bytes` is a `char*`, not a `char`. There must be a problem with the construction of `bytes`, make sure it is correctly null terminated.

Answer (score 0):

But `getline()` isn't returning anything! And if it did, it looks as if you are returning a pointer to a local buffer - `line` - which goes out of scope as soon as the function returns.